# Return only the Hours and Minutes part of the timestamp from Firestore - React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to return the Hours and Minutes part from a timestamp. I can currently return the time but it is returning the seconds as well, which I would like to trim from the time.

```
<Text style={{ fontWeight: "300" }}>{data.endtime.toDate().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB')}</Text>
```

[image]

I am using moment.js and have tried setting the format in the state as "HH:mm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is a quick-and-dirty way to solve your problem, but maybe look into something else more elegant. This is essentially cutting off the last 3 character from the string

```
<Text style={{ fontWeight: "300" }}>{data.endtime.toDate().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB').substring(0, 5)}</Text>
```